# Moving to another host; which tables to move in a database

Tags: database, table

I'm moving my website to a new host and would like to move only my posts and images to the new site. I don't want to use WP export because I've had bad experiences going that route. I don't want to copy the entire database, just copy the posts and images in the database.

What tables can I copy over?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never personally tried this, but your images and posts reside in your `{prefix}posts` (wp_posts) table.  I would also copy `{prefix}postmeta` (wp_postmeta) over.

So copying over those table should do what you want.

Keep in mind that this won't copy your categories and tags (meta), and your comments (comments) they reside in other tables, you could find those easily they have `meta` and `comments` in their names.  Copy those too if you want that.

Comment: Success! Thanks! Also if you use post formats, be sure to copy over `wp_terms` - which is your tags and categories; `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy` - which is your post formats.

Comment: as wp_posts table stores all post types like attachments, custom post types, posts, pages, menus etc so i suggest you to run a sql query to only filter "posts" `SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE 'post_type'='post'` from wp_posts table and then select all export and then import.